# How do I make linked turtles move together in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to model fish movement and need them to form schools when there is more than 1 of the breed in a given patch. So far I have managed to get them to form links when they encounter each other with the function below, but then they continue moving independently. I'd also like to re-scale the color of turtles in a linked group so that the more turtles in the group the darker the color is (I'm guessing this is similar to the way you make contour maps according to environmental gradients but I haven't figured it out yet). 
Any assistance is always appreciated!

```
to form_link

  if count breed_1-here > 1
  [
  ask breed_1
   [create-links-with other breed_1-here]]
end
```

If linking isn't the way to get them to move together, I'm fine with another method.

Comment: How have you tried to get them to move together? What do you mean by moving together? Have you seen the flocking demo in the models library?

Comment: If you want them to move together, you might try using the `tie` command, or you might add simply add some code that gives them all the same heading, like in the Flocking model Matt mentions.

Comment: great thanks guys, I hadn't seen the flocking model but it looks like that will accomplish my goals after some retrofitting. Unfortunately it's so interwoven in to the rest of the model I don't think I'll be able post a new code for future reference by others. Instead I recommend future users to use the following link to find the Flocking model. It's well annotated.
[link](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Flocking)

Comment: I've been working on revising the flock model and run in to another snag, posted here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37261948/netlogo-flocking-model-modification-for-multiple-turtles-in-1-patch) . For those looking to do what's listed above with turtles occupying the same patch, see the linked thread